# How to register an android app user by using Laravel Api

Tags: android, laravel, api, retrofit2

I want to register a user by using laravel api. Api is live on the server also working on postman but in my app its not working. I am using retrofit2 library to use it. Here is the error

2019-05-06 17:23:44.134 473-473/com.engrsoft.www.onlineservices E/response String: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://zattest.com.zawataafnantechnologies.com/newapi/api/register}

> Api.java

```
public interface Api {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("register")

    Call<ResponseBody> register(
            @Field("name") String name,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password
    );
```

> RetrofitClient.java

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL="http://zattest.com.zawataafnantechnologies.com/newapi/api/";

    private static RetrofitClient retrofitClient;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    private RetrofitClient(){
        retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static synchronized RetrofitClient getRetrofitClient(){
        if (retrofitClient == null){
            retrofitClient = new RetrofitClient();
        }
        return retrofitClient;
    }
    public Api getApi(){
        return retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }
```

> RegisterActivity.java

Register Method. Response is coming but not success

```
public void register(){

                        Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient
                                .getRetrofitClient()
                                .getApi()
                                .register(txt_username,txt_email,txt_password);
                        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                                             String s= response.toString();
                                             Log.e("response String", s);
                                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                         }

                                         @Override
                                         public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                         }
                                     }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message

`2019-05-06 17:23:44.134 473-473/com.engrsoft.www.onlineservices E/response String: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK`

does not signify an error response as you said. In fact it is an Ok / success message which means the request has succeeded.

Now you are not logging the response body. So change

`String s= response.toString();`

to

`String s= response.body().toString();` for receiving proper message from backend

Comment: Thanks. Code is already working. Only need to print response in correct form.